# VS 2017 high memory usage while debugging

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with VS after start debugging... I'm using asp.net with webforms, when I start debugging the memory usage is around 100~200mb (starts with master page), since I create the solution a few days ago.

And if I click on the next url, the memory usage rises up like 4~5gb, and my pc gets unresponsive for a few seconds (like 10 or 20 seg)...

I've already uncheck Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging and Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE) without solution... but for some reason when I create the solution I didn't have this issue, and I'm not using any SQL database or code behind yet.

And with VS2013 I don't have this kind of issues...

Any suggestions to fix this? or I need create that solution again?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you debug a new/empty solution in VS2017?

Comment: I don't have problems with debug, and the memory usage stays below ~600mb.